# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'start')

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Giveaway.js

I am getting this error, and I don't know how to fix it, but tutorials use the same thing and don't get this error.

`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'start')`

My code:

```js
case 'start': {
  const gchannel = options.getChannel('channel') || interaction.channel;
  const duration = options.getString('duration');
  const winnerCount = options.getInteger('winners');
  const prize = options.getString('prize');

  client.giveawaysManager
    .start(gchannel, {
      duration: ms(duration),
      winnerCount,
      prize,
      messages: {
        giveaway: ' **GIVEAWAY STARTED**',
        giveawayEnded: ' **GIVEAWAY ENDED** ',
        winMessage: 'Congratulations, {winners}! You won **{this.prize}**!',
      },
    })
    .then(async () => {
      successembed.setDescription('giveaway successfully started.');
      wait(4000);
      interaction.reply({ embeds: [successembed], ephemeral: true });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      errorembed.setDescription(`An error has occured \n\`${err}\``);
      wait(4000);
      interaction.reply({ embeds: [errorembed], ephemeral: true });
    });
}
```

The error is in:

```js
client.giveawaysManager.start(gchannel, {
  duration: ms(duration),
  winnerCount,
  prize,
  messages: {
    giveaway: ' **GIVEAWAY STARTED**',
    giveawayEnded: ' **GIVEAWAY ENDED** ',
    winMessage: 'Congratulations, {winners}! You won **{this.prize}**!',
  },
})
```

Comment: It means `client.giveawaysManager` is `undefined`. What do you expect it to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not client.giveawaysManager, it needs to be constructed by itself:

```
manager= new GiveawaysManager(client, options(opt), init(opt));
```

And then it is called this way:

```
manager.start(gchannel, {
  duration: ms(duration),
  winnerCount,
  prize,
  messages: {
    giveaway: ' **GIVEAWAY STARTED**',
    giveawayEnded: ' **GIVEAWAY ENDED** ',
    winMessage: 'Congratulations, {winners}! You won **{this.prize}**!',
  },
})
```

DOC: https://discord-giveaways.js.org/GiveawaysManager.html

Comment: the giveaways manager is with my own database so i have define the manager in another file with module .exports 
this is thecode : https://srcb.in/8kCN0kOUwr
and for the model for the database this is the code : https://sourceb.in/7bMktjnU6k